# Why am I getting cd: no such file or directory error?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I made a file on terminal
by using mkdir -p examples/test1
I can't access to test1 file

I put cd ~/test1 (current state at) examples folder

cd: no such file or directory

it pops up...
I can see there test1 file exist by typing ls command.

Comment: This question is not directly related to programming and is more appropriate to ask on one of the other sister sites to stackoverflow: https://askubuntu.com/, https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

"~" stands for "current user home directory", so you are trying to "cd" change dir into somewhere like /users/your_current_user_name/test1 (in case your "users" space is located in root).

To debug it you could use "echo" command like this

```
echo ~/test1
```

it will show where this path is located

Comment: I rly appreciated ur help! I found meaning of ~  In terminal just now